# Can't retrieve android preferences from preference.xml

Tags: android-fragments, android-preferences

I have been looking at preferences in android, but I think I must be getting something wrong.
My basic idea is to have a preference.xml file (located in res/xml), which stores a bunch of data, including ListPreference etc.
I have set default values in the XML, but when I try to retrieve the values in a separate fragment, it can't seem to find the preference.

Code of the function in my Fragment:

```
public static void attemptToAddToCalendar(final Context context, final SessionEntity session){

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Toast.makeText(context, "preferences are" + sharedPreferences.getString("pref_addToCalendarAutomatically-list", "Unknown"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Code of the preferences.xml;

```
<ListPreference
            android:key="pref_addToCalendarAutomatically-list"
            android:entries="@array/pref_ARaddToCalendarAutomatically"
            android:entryValues="@array/pref_ARaddToCalendarAutmaticallyValues"
            android:defaultValue="2"
            android:summary="Add favorites to calendar"
            android:title="Calendar Options" ></ListPreference>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

The array 
Now this will only output the text "preferences are Unknown", which evidently means it can't find the values. But I don't understand why.

Comment: **1** - in `/res/xml` is only the **layout** of your preference Screen. **2** - Your preference file is located in `/data/data/your.app.name/shared_prefs/your.app.name_preferences.xml` **3** I doubt that `pref_addToCalendarAutomatically-list` is a valid key name (because of the **-**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the comment! It was indeed only the layout. In hindsight it's kind of obvious, but I was kind of blind...

For anyone that stumbles across the same thing, I modified my code as follows:

Fragment function:

```
  public static void attemptToAddToCalendar(final Context context, final SessionEntity session){

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        Toast.makeText(context, "preferences are " + sharedPreferences.getString("prefAddToCalendarAutomaticallylist", "Unknown"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And the XML accordingly:

```
<ListPreference
        android:key="prefAddToCalendarAutomaticallyList"
        android:entries="@array/prefARaddToCalendarAutomatically"
        android:entryValues="@array/prefARaddToCalendarAutomaticallyValues"
        android:defaultValue="2"
        android:summary="Add favorites to calendar"
        android:title="Calendar Options" >
</ListPreference>
```

This was driving me nuts, so thanks again!